# Используя BeautifulSoup find_all в список добавляются не все элементы которые есть на сайте

Tags: python, beautiful-soup

Используя BeautifulSoup для того чтобы получить на сайте цены всех квартир, их адреса и ссылки на объявление, в список добавляются не все элементы (только 9, когда на сайте их 40). Классы у всех идентичные. Сначала я думала, может проблема в том, что сайт нужно проскролить вниз, но элементы добавляются в разброс, не первые 9. Ниже прикреплю код:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

headers = {
    'User-Agent': "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) "
                  "Chrome/101.0.4951.54 Safari/537.36",
    'Accept-Language': 'ru-RU,ru;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7'
}
response = requests.get("https://www.zillow.com/homes/for_rent/1-_beds/?searchQueryState=%7B%22pagination%22%3A%7B%7D%2C%22usersSearchTerm%22%3Anull%2C%22mapBounds%22%3A%7B%22west%22%3A-122.56276167822266%2C%22east%22%3A-122.30389632177734%2C%22south%22%3A37.69261345230467%2C%22north%22%3A37.857877098316834%7D%2C%22isMapVisible%22%3Atrue%2C%22filterState%22%3A%7B%22fr%22%3A%7B%22value%22%3Atrue%7D%2C%22fsba%22%3A%7B%22value%22%3Afalse%7D%2C%22fsbo%22%3A%7B%22value%22%3Afalse%7D%2C%22nc%22%3A%7B%22value%22%3Afalse%7D%2C%22cmsn%22%3A%7B%22value%22%3Afalse%7D%2C%22auc%22%3A%7B%22value%22%3Afalse%7D%2C%22fore%22%3A%7B%22value%22%3Afalse%7D%2C%22pmf%22%3A%7B%22value%22%3Afalse%7D%2C%22pf%22%3A%7B%22value%22%3Afalse%7D%2C%22mp%22%3A%7B%22max%22%3A3000%7D%2C%22price%22%3A%7B%22max%22%3A872627%7D%2C%22beds%22%3A%7B%22min%22%3A1%7D%7D%2C%22isListVisible%22%3Atrue%2C%22mapZoom%22%3A12%7D", headers=headers)
web_page = response.text

soup = BeautifulSoup(web_page, "html.parser")
dev = soup.select(".list-card-info a")

addresses = [x.get_text() for x in dev]
print(addresses)

price_data = soup.find_all(class_='list-card-price')
prices = [x.get_text().split("+")[0] for x in price_data]
print(prices)

all_price_elements = soup.select(".list-card-heading")
all_prices = []

for x in dev:
    link = x.get('href')
    if "http" not in link:
        link = f'https://www.zillow.com{link}'
    print(link)
```

Comment: Сайт динамический. Используйте селениум.

Comment: сайт динамический, попробуйте сделать через [bs4 selenium](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=z4kSFUwnL5A)